# What is the difference between HTML Lint and HTML Hint?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3, lint, hint

What is the difference between HTML Lint and HTML Hint Sublime packages?

Both work within SublimeLinter and both appear to show errors or warnings in my HTML code. So is there a difference?

UPDATE
From doing a bit more digging, it appears that both Lint and Hint are different words for the same thing: checking/validating/linting code.

Comment: Different tools by different people to do similar jobs. I expect an exhaustive list of the specific differences would be out of scope for SO (and go out of date when new versions are released).

Comment: Okay, they are meant to do a similar job. That's good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both [lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) packages for HTML.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmllint
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlhint

Packages require unique names.

- They are both published in 2014 (~8 years ago).
- HTMLHint came out a few months before htmllint
- I switched over to HTMLHint as they seem to be actively developed. (Last publish is 3 months vs htmllint's 3 years)
- I do miss htmllint's ability to [define tag bans](https://github.com/htmllint/htmllint/wiki/Options#tag-bans)

Note: While I don't recommend it, it is possible to run both.
In package.json

```js
    "scripts": {
    ...
     "lint": "npm-run-all --parallel lint:ts lint:scss lint:html lint:html-tagban",
        "lint:html": "npx htmlhint \"**/*.html\"",
        "lint:html-tagban": "npx htmllint \"**/*.html\"",
        "lint:scss": "npx stylelint \"**/*.scss\" --cache",
        "lint:ts": "npx eslint \"**/*.ts\"",
}
```